# Creating a Flutter SDK Without Using a Plugin: How to Structure Code for Shared Usage in Native Projects

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, mobile-application, dart-pub

I'm exploring the possibility of developing a Flutter SDK that can be used not only in Flutter apps but also seamlessly integrated into native Android and iOS projects. I want to understand if it's feasible to achieve this goal without creating a dedicated Flutter plugin or package.

Is it possible to structure a Flutter project in a way that allows for shared usage in native projects? I'm looking for insights into organizing code, creating bindings or interfaces for core logic, and any potential challenges or limitations. If anyone has experience or suggestions on this matter, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

I've been exploring the development of a Flutter SDK that can be utilized not only in Flutter applications but also integrated into native Android and iOS projects. In my initial attempts, I've considered organizing my Flutter project in a modular way, extracting core logic into separate Dart files, and investigating the use of Dart bindings for potential integration with native projects.

I was expecting to find insights from the community regarding the feasibility of this approach. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding if it's possible to structure a Flutter project for shared usage in native projects without creating a dedicated plugin or package. I'm seeking guidance on best practices, potential challenges, and any examples or experiences that might be relevant to achieving this goal.

Thank you!